# Nested EL Expression failing

Tags: jsf, el

I have an expression as follows

```
#{af:formatNamed2(repo['PARAM'],'NUMBER', someScope.CurrentWorkerIndex, 'TOTAL_NUMBER', someScope.TotalNumberOfWorkers)}"
```

I need the value for the last param to be switched between conditions as follows:

```
someScope.TotalNumberOfWorkers < 0 ? 500 : someScope.TotalNumberOfWorkers
```

I tried all these but failed:

test one:

```
#{af:formatNamed2(repo['PARAM'],'NUMBER', someScope.CurrentWorkerIndex, 'TOTAL_NUMBER', [someScope.TotalNumberOfWorkers < 0 ? 500 : someScope.TotalNumberOfWorkers])}"
```

test two:

```
#{af:formatNamed2(repo['PARAM'],'NUMBER', someScope.CurrentWorkerIndex, 'TOTAL_NUMBER', (someScope.TotalNumberOfWorkers < 0 ? 500 : someScope.TotalNumberOfWorkers))}"
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for my dumbness, think i figured out.

Problem is with the  '<' symbol:

```
someScope.TotalNumberOfWorkers < 0 ? 500 : someScope.TotalNumberOfWorkers
```

Correct:

```
someScope.TotalNumberOfWorkers lt 0 ? 500 : someScope.TotalNumberOfWorkers
```

We need to use 'lt' for '<' and 'gt' for '>'